# Error at Login page - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I've successfully created a custom user using `AbstractBaseUser` and I'm now trying to create the login page using CBV `LoginView` as follows:

```
class UserLogin(LoginView):
    authentication_form = UserLoginForm
    template_name = 'registration/login.html'
```

I have redirected `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` as required in settings. The form I am using is as follows:

```
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(label='username')
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
```

but I keep getting thrown the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'
```

Any ideas? I would guess it's to do with the way I have implemented the CBV but a quick explanation of what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: The error doesn't look like it is related to the code you have provided.

Comment: The error is likely in your urls.py. Check the parameters you are passing to as_view.